# Comparing results from reference coding and orthogonal coding in a linear model?

Tags: bayesian, negative-binomial-distribution, zero-inflation, categorical-encoding

The problem:  I'm trying to fit a zero-inflated negative binomial model to count data (catches of larval fish).  I have three factors, and an offset variable, which is the volume of water filtered by the net.  The fish were collected in a lake partitioned into 6 zones, and each zone is partitioned into onshore, near shore, and offshore areas (which we call strata).  These are the first two factors, and the third is the year of collection.  Considering the offset, the response in the model is density of fish per cubic meter of water.

My colleague has estimates of the total volume of water in the zones and strata.  We would very much like to use a Bayesian approach, so that we can use the lake volumes and fish density estimates to calculate the expected total number of fish in each zone-strata combination, and to obtain 95% credible intervals on those abundance estimates.

I am using Proc CountReg in SAS, which includes a Bayesian option.  The difficulty is that although the procedure readily provides a solution to the basic model, the ensuing Markov chains don't converge for some of the parameters, even with huge numbers.  I have been using reference cell coding for the design matrix in this analysis.  I've tried some reparameterizations, etc. and they don't help.

I had the idea that switching to orthogonal reference cell coding (applying a Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization) to the basic design matrix) would help, and it does - the chains converge nicely.

However, it seems to me that the predicted values from the reference cell coding and the predicted values from the orthogonal coding should match.  They are close to one another, but not identical, and there are a few larger differences.

My question is whether they should they match?  It certainly seems to me that they should.  And are the differences between the two that I'm seeing just due to rounding errors and the difference in the calculations being used?

Thanks, and apologies for the long-winded question.